# Why does the log_in helper method work in Hartl tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the helper method log_in in the Hartl tutorial in app/helpers

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end
```

IN the controller we call it like this:

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Why does this work? The method seems to be an instance method but who is the receiver of the method in the create action?

Answer (score 2):

This method is called on the controller's instance. Controller instantiates during HTTP request flow. SessionsController includes methods from SessionsHelper module. Try to rename  method's name slightly and invoke in the SessionsController `log_inn` instead of `log_in` and you will see something similar to `undefined method 'log_inn' for #<SessionsController:0x1047d4825>`. So as you see receiver is the instance of the SessionsController class.

Answer (score 0):

The `login` method "works" by simply assigning the `user_id` to the session variable. The session is persisted between requests and used to determine whether or not a user is logged in or not. For more information on sessions see this rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions